# Accessing an instance variable from another class for cocos2d project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, instance-variables

In my cocos2d game, I have a "powerup" of sorts where, once attained, the character becomes blue, the platform becomes blue, and so does the background. I'm not sure if I am implementing this in the best way so if you have other suggestions please do share!:)

I created a class **Blue** that has an instance variable called **blueCalled**

I imported this class to both my "Platform" class as well as my "Player" class.

The powerup and player colliding code is inside my Platform class. This is the code for when the powerup is hit:

```
    // try remove powerup
- (void) tryRemovePowerup
{
    NSMutableArray * currentPowerUpArray = [self getcurrentPowersArr];

    if(currentPowerUpArray)
    {
        int playerY = ((CCLayer*)(self.player)).position.y;
        for(int x=0; x<[currentPowerUpArray count];x++)
        {
            CCSprite *powerup = [currentPowerUpArray objectAtIndex:x];

            if(abs(powerup.position.x+powerup.parent.position.x-[Player initX])<50)
            {
                if(abs(powerup.position.y+blueberry.parent.position.y-playerY)<30 && powerup.visible && powerup.visible)
                {
                    [power.parent powerup cleanup:YES];

                    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
                    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"yay.wav" pitch:1 pan:0 gain:1];
                    // THIS IS WHERE ALL OF EFFECTS SHOULD HAPPEN
                    NSLog(@"powerup hit");

                }
            }
        }
    }


    [self hitTestOB];
}
```

The place of  // THIS IS WHERE ALL OF EFFECTS SHOULD HAPPEN is where I want to make everything blue. Right now, I plan to do this by setting the instance variable in the Blue class to YES.

In the methods that take care of the 1. frames of the main player, 2. background, and 3. platform frames, I have an if statement checking if the instance variable of the Blue class is YES or NO and it acts accordingly. 
However, I don't know how to use the instance variable from the Blue class in my platform and player class, also, I'm not 100% confident this is the best way to implement a powerup.

Thank you for any help you can provide me :)

Go iOS!

Comment: you might find this helpful: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/files/cocos2d-essential-reference-sample/Strategies_for_Accessing_Other_Nodes.html

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you want to access an iVar of another object, you should make a property to access it. This is not an exception to that rule, but I'll tell you how to do it anyways.

Objective C objects are inherently C structures. This means that the `->` operator works on them. In this case, you would want to use `blue->blueCalled`, where `blue` is the instance of your `Blue` class.

Visibility is the key to this working (or failing). You can only use this if the iVar is declared within the `@interface` in the header file and not following and `@private` or `@protected` declaration.